# Overlay on an Image in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have an app, in which i used TouchImageView to include an image, and implement zooming using pinch zoom, panning, etc. It's working fine. Now i need to include some kind of an image, or a text written as an overlay on the TouchImageView image.

I have tried to draw using a canvas, but that draws on the background, rather than the TouchImageView. So how do i implement it, so that the image has a pointer or overlay on it, and it can be zoomed, panned, etc.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit - I'm attaching my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/rel"
><com.reva.restauranthome.Panel android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/panelView">

</com.reva.restauranthome.Panel>

<ZoomControls android:id="@+id/zoomControls1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ZoomControls></RelativeLayout>
```

And in my code, I used it this way!

```
Panel v =(Panel)findViewById(R.id.panelView);
          v.bringToFront();
```

Cheers,

Nithin

Answer (score 0):

I would use relativelayout and let the overlay view always be on top.

```
overlayView.bringToFront();
```

will bring it to the front.

Comment: Thanks, i had the same idea. Need a bit help. I have a custom class, which extends View (for the overlays). And how do i link it in the onCreate() method. I tried it out this way! View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.panelView), but v returns Null

Comment: Could you supply your xml and your code? Which kind of layout is your custom view in?